# Trying to install pygame on el capitan and having issue with the last part

Tags: python, macos, pygame, pip

I'm trying to install Pygame on Mac OSX El Capitan and have managed to get all but the last part of the install instructions to work.

I'm following this set of instructions:

http://pygame.org/wiki/macintosh

Everything worked fine with the exception of the last command i have to enter which is:

```
pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

I do have pip installed and whenever I type this into the Terminal it responds with:

```
Kiras-MacBook-Pro:~ Kiro$  pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip3: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have tried looking around on the net for instructions or help with installing on El Capitan but all I have found are the instructions I am following repeated on other sites.

And other people having the same issue but with no solutions posted.

Comment: What do you get when you type `python3` in the terminal?

Comment: it responds with this

Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 12 2015, 11:00:19) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this same problem. I think the issue is that pip3 is looking in the wrong path -- /usr/local/opt instead of /usr/local/bin. I just solved it by doing this:

```
mkdir /usr/local/opt/python3
mkdir /usr/local/opt/python3/bin
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.5 /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5
```

After that, pip3 seems to run fine.